# UISearchBar black lines/border

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

I'm getting some odd black lines above and below a UISearchBar and I'm not quite sure how to get rid of them. Setting the style of the UISearchBar to minimal solves that problem, but then it doesn't have the background colour I'd like.

Any ideas what's causing this? I've looked over a few similar questions, but none seem to do what I want. Many thanks in advance!

[image: Search bar showing a black border at the top and bottom]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
searchBar.layer.borderWidth = 1;
searchBar.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
```

Comment: That's perfect, thank you! Any idea why we need that? Event explicitly setting a borderWidth = 0 doesn't work.

Comment: I believe this border is an intentional feature from Apple to have `UISearchBar`  come outstanding. And at the same time we have been given ways to tweak per our needs :).

Answer (score 5):

For Swift 3:

```
searchBar.layer.borderWidth = 1
searchBar.layer.borderColor = searchBar.barTintColor?.cgColor
```

Answer (score 3):

By setting empty image to background will solve the issue

```
self.searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
```

Comment: This answer seems more correct. UISearchBarBackground is a UIImageView and is the one responsible for adding these borders. By adding a border to the searchBar layer the lines/borders may become invisible but they are still there.